# Integration of PayTm payment in iOS

Tags: ios, payment-gateway

Could anyone please tell me how can I implement payTm payment gateway in my iOS app. Searched a lot in internet but couldn't get any result. Not sure whether they provide any SDK or API to use.

I was searching for payment gateways which are mainly focussed in India. found `One97's` `Paytm Payments` but not sure how to implement this in iOS app.

Could any one please help me.

Comment: check this link also : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41073921/3400991

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Paytm has SDK for both iOS and Android platform. It is integrated already on few merchants. Write to us at `pgsales@paytm.com` and we will send you SDK and Integration document along with test credentials.

Comment: @Prasad Devadiga , Did you integrated that, I just want to confirm , does it worth. Please reply!

Comment: @Prasad Devadiga , Did you integrated the Paytm or integrated with some other payment

Comment: @Prema : Send you mail. please send me that SDK

Comment: @SachinSiwal PayTM integration as Vicky said, is only for registered companies. If you are individual developer, you won't get access to their SDK. Not sure what's the whole point of hiding even the test account from developers. This is a total loss of business (for both developers and PayTM). Documents needed: VAT Certificate/Service Tax/ Company Registration / Shop Act License / Company COI, Anyone of (Company proprietor PAN), Proprietor/Authorized Sign KYC - Voter ID / Adhar Card / DL / Passport. Cancelled Cheque, PO on companies letter head.

Comment: We integrate PayTM in my personal app, when we check paytm in Android device, it's working. 
Only in Iphone devices , it's not working. Can anyone please suggest some comments ,  Did iphone is blocking the url

Answer (score 2):

PayTM is only for Private Ltd. companies. Unlike PayPal(unfortunately not in India), which provides access to there SDK for developers as well.

If you want to integrate PayTM, you would have to contact them and they will give you a list of things (which includes: DIN number, company name, PAN.. etc) which you should have before getting the SDK access.

This to me is pretty outdated thing. PayTM should provide access to developers to at least test their platform. Sandbox account is something developers can test their app before going live they can definitely request for all the needed details. In that sense, PayPal integration is way way better.

@Prerna Kalra Please let your team know that developers want to test their integration before going into all the official details.

Answer (score 1):

To integrate with Paytm payments, you would require an SDK that they provide for the same. You need to get in touch with the Paytm's integration team for the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a lot of people are asking this and Paytm is not really ready to make its own documentation. The only way I know of is to download their sdk and contact their customer care with your query about integration. And await their response for installation queries.