# Facing issue in paytm integration?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, paytm

I am creating checksum url and verified checksum url for ios and android using node js.On the mobile side they have used sdk for paytm.I have used this link to create and verified checksum:

```
https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_NodeJs/blob/master/checksum/checksum.js
```

But after hitting checksum url from mobile side to my server our app google playstore page open.Not paytm wallet.
Please help,if anyone has any idea about this.

Thanks.

Comment: here is the link for iOS integration PAYTM : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41073921/3400991 but basic remain same

Answer (score 0):

```
  PaytmMerchant Merchant = new PaytmMerchant(
            "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumGenerator.jsp",
            "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCheckSumVerify.jsp");
```

Comment: Thanks @Priya,but what if the checksum genaration and verification done on server.Then i guess we need to provide server url .

Comment: maybe you could explain the code to help the OP use it or adapt it.

Comment: @Abhisheksaini you can host it on server too , in adroid it works if u handle it app side but in iOS it only work if we host it on server side , so try both way whtever suited you

Comment: Thanks all ,for giving me suggestion but i have resolved my issue.The issue is with the response sending from my side after the checksum is created.The response should be in the proper format as define in @Paytm documentation then only mobile sdk can process it.

Comment: Hi, Currently integrating Paytm in Android App. Checksumhash is generating on the server side but I cannot able to Verify checksum in AndroidApp.Can you please help me ?    Thanks in Advance